# Mapping Joda time to Cassandra's Date type

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

What is the recommended way to map Joda time to Cassandra's Date type when mapping with Spring-data's cassandra module? Is there an equivalent to the @Type annotation in JPA/Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is being addressed with this pending ticket:
https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-721

Once resolved, the java driver mapping would allow custom types to be mapped against cassandra data model.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a clean way to register converters with spring-data-cassandra.

You can still use `java.util.Date` for your fields (the framework will access them through reflection), and use encapsulation to provide the type you want :

```
@Table("measure")
public class Measure {

    @PrimaryKey("id") private String id;
    @Column("timestamp") private java.util.Date timestamp;
    @Column("data") private Double data;

    /** 
     * Convert java.util.Date -> org.joda.time.DateTime 
     */
    public DateTime getTimestamp() {
        // Simple example, beware of the timezone
        return new DateTime(ts);
    }

    // Constructor and other getters omitted
}
```